# Ways to model child view model interaction with the parent view model?

Tags: events, design-patterns, mvvm

Consider some sort of Personal Information Management presentation with a PimDetailVm that takes a Person object as it's Model. The presentation will manage various aspects about a person (name, contact points, addresses, etc), which together would bloat the original view model.

So I want to split off satellite view models for each. The original view model still has responsibility for permitting and committing updates though, so at a minimum its needs to know whether IsDirty and IsValid are true, and the current state of the Model.

Cheers,
Berryl

## UPDATE

There is (was) too much text in my original post; maybe organizing this better will get more responses and leave a trail of something useful, so

Parent / Child synchronization options

1. INPC

   - Pros - already implemented by VM
   - Cons - fires multiple times, arguably should be restricted for DataBinding only
2. Mediator

   - Pros - clean separation of intention
   - Cons - not sure how to implement and use in a generic fashion
3. Event Aggregator

   - Pros - common abstraction
   - Cons - not sure how to implement and use in a generic fashion
4. Domain event (ie, PersonUpdated) and let the model be the synch source

   - Pros - arguably the event belongs here, simplifies VM infrastructure
   - Cons - not sure
5. Intra View Model Event (ie, ViewModelUpdated)

   - Pros - cleaner than INPC since it fires only one and its intention is clear
   - Cons - not sure
6. Hard link  (ie, Parent.Update())

   - Pros - intention is clear, easier to debug
   - Cons - tight coupling
7. inherit from Dependency Object

   - Pros - Will likes it
   - Cons - not reusable, tight coupling to WPF dispatcher
8. inherit VM from DynamicObject

   - Pros - you can do what you want
   - Cons - changes ViewModel structure, complex to inexperienced programmers
9. incorporate AOP with an interceptor

   - Pros - do what you want
   - Cons - learning curve, not obvious

Comment: I usually just make my ViewModels extend DO and compose them in the xaml--`<this:ParentViewModel x:Name="Parent" Child="{StaticResource Child}" />` but some people hate that.  Like I hate prefacing question titles with tags.  A burning hatred that hollows out the core, leaving only blackened cinders.

Comment: Well if it helps to make your disposition sunnier, I like your title better. "How to compose view model relationships" might have worked well too! Have you some code or a link that better demonstrates your approach? Why do the haters hate it so much?

Comment: Honestly, there isn't any special code.  You just extend DependencyObject and treat your ViewModels like any other DO.  Create them as resources in App.xaml (where StaticResource can find them everywhere).  You can assign them here and there using StaticResource markup extension, you can bind them to each other, etc etc.  Some people hate it because they believe ViewModels should be implementation agnostic.  But who ever used the same ViewModel type in two different platforms?  That kind of code reuse is non-existent.  Treating them like everything else in xaml is super easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close this out really, Pete Brown addresses some aspects of this [here](http://10rem.net/blog/2010/12/16/strategies-for-improving-inotifypropertychanged-in-wpf-and-silverlight).

Josh Smith also has two very useful classes in hi [MVVM Foundation library](http://mvvmfoundation.codeplex.com/) that address this problem: Messenger and PropertyObserver.